# How to parse xml file having special symbol like '°'(degree celecius symbol)

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

well i am using tool for my Reporting in c#
Tool is Fyi-Reporting tool in which i parse my xml file and generate report

well i have folowing xml text which gives me error that can not parse "°c"

```
SELECT TimeStamp, "T(°C)_0" as [T_0(°C)]  FROM Person
```

can anyone suggest me how to parse specia symbol in xml file

Comment: The encoding you're using doesn't support it, maybe unicode could fix it?

Comment: If your XML file uses the correct encoding, it should just work out of the box. You should tell us what encoding it declares that it uses (if any) and what bytes are used to represent the degree sign.